# can we not access the anonymous class data members if they are not declared in parent one?

Tags: java, oop, anonymous-class

```
class Parent{
  String h;
  Parent(String s){
    h = s;
  }
}
public class Child{ 
public static void main(String args[]){
   Parent p = new Parent("fcghj"){          // anonymous class
            private int y = 9;
  };
  System.out.println(p.h);
  System.out.println(p.y);              // error
}
}
```

Error showing: cannot find symbol y in Parent

Is there any way to access y outside the anonymous class if it is not declared in the Parent class?

Are we only able to declare those fields and methods that exist in the Parent class for just the sake of overloading, hiding and overriding in anonymous class?

Comment: 1. As you can see, no, you can't access y from outside. 2. As you can see, the compiler lets you declare y, and y doesn't overload, override or hide anything.

Comment: @JBNizet : Just curious here, since we created an object `p`, shouldn't we be able to access `y` using that object?

Comment: No, since the declared type of the variable is Parent, and Parent doesn't have any member field named y. That is not limited to anonymous classes. If you use `Object p = new Point(1, 2)`, you can't use p.x and p.y, because the declared type of the variable p is Object, not Point.

Comment: Thanks. But just thought since we are creating an object of Parent itself (through an annonymous class) I felt it was possible to access it.

Answer (score 0):

*Anonymous* code stays *anonymous* if not assigned, also look at it as simple block, as for initialize block you don't expect to get the value outside:

```
public class Child { 

  {          // initialize block
            int y = 9;
  }
public static void main(String args[]){
   Parent p = new Parent("fcghj");
  System.out.println(p.h);
  System.out.println(y);              // error
}
```

You can change/add Parent constructor with int parameter to use it later

```
class Parent{
  String h;
  int y;
  Parent(String s, int y){
    h = s;
    this.y = y;
  }
```